# Turning a ternary operator into if else statement on return

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using a ternary operator as follows:

```
return $scope.productWithEAN(EAN).then(function(product) {
   return (product) ? product : $scope.createProduct(productID, name);
  });
});
```

I want to now point to a function if `return (product) ? product`

I believe that this is best done with an if else statement.  I have created this, however I am getting an unexpected return token:

```
return $scope.productWithEAN(EAN).then(function(product) {
  if (return (product) ? product) {
      console.log("product is here");
      //$scope.checkOrUpdateProduct;
    },else {
      console.log("product not here");
      //$scope.createProduct(productID, name);
    };
  });
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your new code has some syntax errors: you are now using the ternary operator with only two operands (it has to have three), you have a `return` in your `if` condition, and you have a comma before your `else`.

Comment: You cannot do that. A `return` statement can involve an *expression*, but an `if ... else` is not an expression; it's a different statement type. Similarly, you can't embed a `return` where an `if` expects an expression.

Comment: The statement could be: `return product || $scope.createProduct(productID, name);`, which might be even clearer than an *if..else* sequence.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy - a bit more reading required I think!!! I assumed that it was something like this that was breaking things!

Comment: @RobG not sure how you'd head off to two different functions in this code?

Comment: Exactly the same: `return a() || b()`. If the return value of `a()` is truthy, it's returned, otherwise the return value of `b()` is returned (regardless of whether it's truthy or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `if (return ...)`. If you want to rewrite it to a if else statement, you can use this:

```
return $scope.productWithEAN(EAN).then(function(product) {
    if (product) {
        console.log("product is here");
        return $scope.checkOrUpdateProduct();
    } 
    console.log("product not here");
    return $scope.createProduct(productID, name);
});
```

Note that there isn't the need of `if else`, if the `if` condition meets, the else part will never be reached as we `return` inside the `if`. So you can just `return` inside the `if` and don't need an `else` thereafter.

Comment: I strongly advice you to do this. Trading readability for smaller code is not a good long term strategy. Michael's code is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Just so that I understand better, is the (product) expecting a boolean return i.e: here  / not here?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a boolean. If it holds something (whatever but undefined, null, false), the if condition will hit @MrT

Comment: @Michael Great.  Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @Michael I'm observing that if there is no product, then what would be the else statement `console.log("product not here");
    return $scope.createProduct(productID, name);` is run (this writes an entry to a database).  However if a product is present, then it runs both the if statement & the `console.log("product not here");
    return $scope.createProduct(productID, name);` code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow - can you explain? If there is a product, everything after the if statement's closing `}` isn't run right now. Do you want to change that behavior? @MrT

Comment: I've just read your answer again & I'll have to look through my production code to work out whats going on.  Basically, when a product is in my database (which is what productWithEAN checks for), then I get two console logs - "product is here" & "product not here" & their associated functions are also run.  Having thought it through further I think its beyond the scope of this though.  Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Actually, figured it... Really stupid.  I have the first return commented out!!! Tiredness kills...